# Translation from NASM to GAS

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, gnu-assembler, att

how do I translate `mov [ebx], al` from NASM to GAS?
I tried `mov %al, (%ebx)` but it does segmentatiob fault.

Another question, lets say I have an array in GAS `.lcomm array, 50`
Do I have to put a dollar($) sign in `array` like this: `mov %rbx, $array` or need not to?

Any answer would be helpful :)

Comment: Assemble with NASM, disassemble with `objdump -d` (or with [`objconv`](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) to get a file you can actually assemble.

Answer (score 3):

How about [intel2gas](http://www.niksula.cs.hut.fi/~mtiihone/intel2gas/)?

```
usage: intel2gas [options] [-o outfile] [infile]
where options include:
    -h        this help
    -i        convert from intel to at&t format (default)
    -g        convert from at&t to intel format
    -m -t     convert from masm/tasm to at&t format
    -c        understand C style comments
    -I        convert inline assembler (intel to at&t only)
    -d        output all % chars as %%
    -V        show version
    infile and outfile default to stdin/stdout
```

Comment: Intel2gas now lives in github: https://github.com/skywind3000/Intel2GAS

Comment: Wow... This tool is awful.

Answer (score 2):

Assemble with NASM, disassemble with `objdump -d` to get the AT&T syntax version of any single instruction.

Or use Agner Fog's [`objconv`](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) to disassemble to a `.S` file with GAS AT&T syntax you can actually assemble directly.  (it puts labels on branch targets).  It still doesn't really handle converting data, though, mostly code I think.

---

BTW, with GAS you can use `.intel_syntax noprefix`, but it's MASM-style not NASM, so `mov eax, symbol` is a load, not a `mov`-immediate of the address.  (You'd need `mov eax, OFFSET symbol` in GAS `.intel_syntax`). 
 See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info for more about the differences between NASM and MASM.

---

`mov [ebx], al` and `mov %al, (%ebx)` are the same instruction: a one-byte store of `al` using the `ebx` alone as the address.  If that segfaulted, then that instruction alone isn't the problem.  Either other instructions are wrong, or you have a different kind of problem.  Perhaps you assembled your GAS code as 64-bit?  [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain).

Answer (score 1):

you can use objdump (otool on osx) to disassemble into gas format.

Comment: It's Intel-syntax, but it's MASM-style, not NASM.  e.g. `mov eax, symbol` is a load from memory in GAS and MASM, but a `mov`-immediate of the address in NASM.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info.

Answer (score 0):

First up, `mov %al, %ecx` can't really fault because it's not accessing memory. Hell, it shouldn't even assemble because they are of different size.
That said, the correct translation of your nasm code is `mov %al, (%ecx)` which will write `al` into memory at address `ecx`.

For the other question: you need the `$` if you want to reference the address. As such, `mov %rbx, $array` is invalid because you can't assign to the address. If you want to store `rbx` into the first item of the array, write `mov %rbx, array`. If you want to load the first item, use `mov array, %rbx`. If you want to load the address of the first item, do `mov $array, %rbx` or use `lea` which is special and doesn't need the `$`.

Comment: Nice, thanks. sorry I have missed something. I tried that, it worked for ecx but not for ebx. I have tried mov %al, (%ebx) and movb %al, (%ebx), still does seg fault. What do I do?

Comment: That means `ebx` has an invalid address. Maybe you didn't load it with an address. I can only guess without seeing the whole code. Also, it it's supposed to be 64 bit code, `ebx` feels wrong.

Comment: Well, I did something like: push %ebx and pop %ebx then after pop, it does seg fault. Is there something wrong?