# Assembly: boot loader for custom OS keyboard support

Tags: assembly, x86, att, osdev, multiboot

I have a working simple custom OS (doesn't do much for now :D). Right now i'm using an assembly file (boot.s) that has no keyboard support.

The assembly file (boot.s):

```
# set magic number to 0x1BADB002 to identified by bootloader 
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002
# set flags to 0
.set FLAGS,    0
# set the checksum
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)
# set multiboot enabled
.section .multiboot
# define type to long for each data defined as above
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM
# set the stack bottom 
stackBottom:
# define the maximum size of stack to 512 bytes
.skip 512
# set the stack top which grows from higher to lower
stackTop:
.section .text
.global _start
.type _start, @function

_start:
  # assign current stack pointer location to stackTop
    mov $stackTop, %esp
  # call the kernel main source
    call KERNEL_MAIN
    cli
# put system in infinite loop
hltLoop:
    hlt
    jmp hltLoop
.size _start, . - _start
```

I think this is the missing part but it is in intel syntax and i cannot use it.

```
load_idt:
mov edx, [esp + 4]
lidt [edx]
sti
ret

read_port:
mov edx, [esp + 4]
in al, dx   
ret

write_port:
mov edx, [esp + 4]    
mov al, [esp + 4 + 4]  
out dx, al  
ret

keyboard_handler:                 
call keyboard_handler
iretd
```

I'm compiling the boot.s with the following command:

```
as --32 boot.s -o boot.o
```

Can anyone help me translating the keyboard part (Intel syntax) to AT&T? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information on how you can go about translating NASM Intel syntax to GAS's AT&T syntax can be found in this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833928/translation-from-nasm-to-gas), and a lot of useful information is provided in this [IBM article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html). Your code in particular would look like:

```
load_idt:
    mov 4(%esp), %edx
    lidt (%edx)
    sti
    ret

read_port:
    mov 4(%esp), %edx
    in %dx, %al
    ret

write_port:
    mov 4(%esp), %edx
    mov 8(%esp), %al
    out %al, %dx
    ret

keyboard_handler:                 
    call keyboard_handler
    iret
```

In general the biggest differences are:

- With AT&T syntax the source is on the left and destination is on the right and Intel is the reverse.
- With AT&T syntax register names are prepended with a `%`
- With AT&T syntax immediate values are prepended with a `$`
- Memory operands are probably the  biggest difference. NASM uses *[segment:disp+base+index*scale]* instead of GAS's syntax of *segment:disp(base, index, scale)*.

---

### Other Observations

I recommend moving the stack out of the multiboot section into the `.bss` section. The BSS section doesn't generally take up space in the output executable (assuming one is using a sane or default linker script). The stack could be defined this way after the `.text` section:

```
.section .bss
    .lcomm stackBottom 512
stackTop:
```

Comment: The first *write_port* instruction is missing the 4 bytes displacement.

Comment: @SepRoland : Thanks. It appears I accidentally pulled off the displacement during translation.